# I found these images of parts and want to find their part numbers

Tags: part-identification, technic

So I found this lot on the internet but don't trust the seller. What I want to do is find the part numbers of the pieces on the image and buy it from a reliable source. I tried to find it in multiple ways but did not succeed. I also intend to use this on future pieces but it's okay if you can provide only the ones on the picture. Lastly the main piece I'm searching for is the first one.
Thank you in advance.[image: this is the image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find all of these elements listed on Bricklink under "[Technic, Steering](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=141)" category

Assembled combinations are:

1. [Technic, Steering Portal Axle, Housing with Dark Bluish Gray Technic, Steering Wheel Hub 3 Pin Round (92908 / 92909)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92908c01#T=C&C=86)
2. [Technic, Steering Axle with 2 Pin Holes and 2 Axle Holes with Dark Bluish Gray Wheel Hub (23801 / 92909)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=23801c01#T=C&C=11)
3. [Technic, Steering Axle with 2 Pin Holes and 2 Ball Joint Arms with Dark Bluish Gray Wheel Hub (11949 / 92909)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11949c01#T=C&C=86)
4. [Technic, Steering Arm with 4 Ball Joints with Black Wheel Hub (x872 / x873)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x873c01#T=C)
5. [Technic, Steering Axle with 2 Pin Holes with Dark Bluish Gray Wheel Hub (11950 / 92909)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11950c01#T=C)
6. No listing as an assembly
7. No listing as an assembly
8. [Technic, Steering Axle with 2 Pin Holes with Dark Bluish Gray Steering Wheel Hub 3 Pin Holes Round (11950/ 35189)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11950c02#T=C&C=86)

These assemblies consist of following individual elements (listed by the time of the first appearance on a picture):

- [92908 - Technic, Steering Portal Axle, Housing](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92908#T=C&C=86)
- [92909 - Technic, Steering Wheel Hub 3 Pin Round](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92909&idColor=85#T=C&C=85)
- [23801 - Technic, Steering Wheel Hub Holder with 2 Pin Holes and 2 Axle Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=23801#T=C)
- [11949 - Technic, Steering Wheel Hub Holder with 2 Pin Holes and 2 Ball Joint Arms](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11949#T=C&C=86)
- [x873c01 - Technic, Steering Arm with 4 Ball Joints with Black Wheel Hub (x872 / x873)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x873c01#T=C)
- [11950 - Technic, Steering Wheel Hub Holder with 2 Pin Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11950&idColor=0#T=C&C=0)
- [92910 - Technic, Steering Ball Joint Large Open with C-Shape Pivot Frame](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92910#T=C&C=86)
- [92911 - Technic, Steering Ball Joint Large Receptacle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92911#T=C)
- [35189 - Technic, Steering Wheel Hub 3 Pin Holes Round](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=35189&idColor=85#T=C&C=85)

Check out these URLs where you can find which sets each of these elements was included in and you can also purchase ones you need directly on Bricklink.